# Read downloaded file ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am able to download the file from specific URL. But here problem is this file getting saved inside the download folder of the system. Is there any way to save this file locally in project and read this file programmatically?

```
const downloadFile = () => {
    fetch(urlToDownload)
        .then(response => {
            response.blob().then(blob => {
                let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                let a = document.createElement('a');
                a.href = url;
                a.download = 'example.pdf';
                a.click();
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you setting `attachment` headers in the backend?, that will trigger an immediate download.

Comment: What do you mean by 'read' the file. You already have the `Blob` from the response, so what are you missing?

Comment: It should not download in our download folder, I want to use 'example.pdf' in application.